# Angular.io replace selector into table

Tags: angular

I have multiple nested `components` and I am using a `table` as root. The problem is that a `table` is limited using `tbody` and `tr`.

Table component:

```
<table>
   <tbody first-child-component></tbody>
</table>
```

FirstChildComponent:

```
selector: '[first-child-component]'

<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>

<tbody second-child-component [some-input]='an input'...></tbody>
```

SecondChildComponent:

```
selector: '[second-child-component]'

<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
```

I want to be able to delete the `<tbody second-child-component></tbody>` in the generated DOM element so that I can have only the `tr` elements.

I separate the `SecondChildComponent` by his own because it can be called or embedded in other components and `SecondChildComponent` receive some `@input`s from his parent. The only ugly solution I got in mind is to add an `ng-content` tag into `SecondChildComponent` then pass  `FirstChildComponent` to it then include `<tbody second-child-component></tbody>` into `Table component`.

What would be a great solution to deal with that problem?

Comment: what you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: I'm trying to include the `tr`s from `SecondChildComponent` into `FirstChildComponent`.

Comment: yes that i got but what's the scenario here It doesn't make sense to put table tag in one component and tr in other

Comment: Yes it make sense. The table has multiple sections. And the sections use there own data and structure (it maybe a checkbox, list groups). In the case of `SecondChildComponent ` it is a customized `list group`. So I don't want to copy the list group code in case I modify the `list group` in the future. For that I create the `list group` as a component.

Comment: It would be like in OOP using C#, Java or other graphical languages where I have a `Table class` and a class with a `List of Row`.

Comment: I already made that using JQuery.